# NTLM: How to determine if a machine account is a member of security group

Tags: c#

Is there an easy way in .NET code to determine if particular machine account (e.g. MYSERVER001$) is a member of an NT security group?  I would also like to do the same check for an NT user or an NT group (check whether they belong to a particular group)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 3.5, you can consider to use [Principal.IsMemberOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156095.aspx) in  [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

The IsMemberOf() method works with AD security group as well as Distribution List.

More details about how to programming with groups can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924542%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)